# How do I properly set date.timezone in php.ini

Tags: php

I've seen this question asked a number of times, but never seen a satisfactory answer.  I've just installed icinga2 and during setup its giving me the error: "The PHP config `date.timezone' is not defined."

When I set the variable in the php.ini file, and then view phpinfo, it shows me that the default timezone is set, but the variable date.timezone is empty.  See the image:
[image: phpinfo]

I can change the value of the default timezone by changing date.timezone in the php.ini file.  Currently mine reads: `date.timezone = "America/Los_Angeles"`  I can see the result in the default timezone.  I can also change it in .htaccess by adding `php_value date.timezone "America/Los_Angeles"`.  But the value of date.timezone always remains "no value".  I've tried other values in both places and I can see them reflected the default timezone field.  But never in the date.timezone field.

Additional ini files evaluated do not have date.timezone values in them as I grepped the lot of them.  date.timezone is only found in the main php.ini file in /etc/php/7.3/apache2/php.ini.

Despite the default timezone being set correctly, icinga2 expects the date.timezone variable to be set.  Does anyone know how to set the variable?